# Acessar um elemento de um JSON de maneira dinâmica

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
    [{
    "posts": {
        "ID": 452,
        "post_date": "01\/01\/2016 15:30:00",
        "post_title": "Titulo do post"
    },
    "postmeta": {
        "anexo": {
            "size": {
                "value": "615",
                "unit": "KB"
            },
            "extension": "PDF"
        }
    },
    "taxonomies": {
        "tax_teste": {
            "term_id": 15,
            "name": "minha taxonomia",
            "slug": "minha-taxonomia"
        }
    }
}, {
    "posts": {
        "ID": 34,
        "post_date": "28\/11\/2015 10:13:22",
        "post_title": "Titulo do post2"
    },
    "postmeta": {
        "anexo": {
            "size": {
                "value": "39",
                "unit": "KB"
            },
            "extension": "JPG"
        }
    },
    "taxonomies": {
        "tax_teste": {
            "term_id": 132,
            "name": "taxonomia 2",
            "slug": "taxonomia-2"
        },
        "tax_local": {
            "term_id": 52,
            "name": "Rio de Janeiro",
            "slug": "rio-de-janeiro"
        }
    }
}]
```

Tem um exemplo de HTML:

```
html = '<table class="tb-widget-materiais">';
html += '<tr class="item_widget item_widget_left">';
html += '<td class="left">';
html += '<a href="{LINK_MATERIAL}" target="_blank" title="{TITLE_MATERIAL}">';
html += '<img width="{WIDTH_IMG}" height="{HEIGHT_IMG}" src="{SRC_IMG}" class="attachment-eiWidgets size-eiWidgets wp-post-image" alt="{TITLE_MATERIAL}" title="{TITLE_MATERIAL}" />';
html += '</a>';
html += '</td>';
html += '<td class="right">';
html += '<p>{DATA_MATERIAL}</p>';
html += '<h3>';
html += '<a href="{LINK_MATERIAL}" target="_blank" title="{TITLE_MATERIAL}">';
html += '{TITLE_MATERIAL} - {SIZE_MATERIAL}</a>';
html += '</h3>';
html += '</td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '<tr>';
html += '<td>';
html += '<a href="{SLUG_TAXONOMY}">{TAXONOMY}</a>';
html += '</td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '</table>';
```

O JSON é guardado em uma variável, tive de diminuir pra não ficar muito grande aqui no exemplo, mas no modelo de produção há outros elementos.
Tou tendo dificuldade em fazer uma função que receba como parâmetro esse JSON, um HTML e um array com a propriedades, e efetue as trocas.

ex. de chamada da função

```
montaPagina(html,dadosJSON,{"{TITLE_MATERIAL}":"posts.post_title","{SIZE_MATERIAL}":"postmeta.anexo.size.value","{SLUG_TAXONOMY}":"taxonomies.$1.slug","{TAXONOMY}":"taxonomies.$1.name"});
```

Comecei criar a função da seguinte maneira:

```
montaPagina = function(html,dados,argumentos)
{
    var htmlReturn = '';
    var er = new RegExp(/\[/);
    $.each(dados,function(keyDados,valueDados)
    {
        var htmlTmp = html;

        $.each(argumentos,function(keyArgs,valueArgs)
        {
            var filho = valueArgs.split('.');
            var tmp = valueDados;

            $(filho).each(function(k,v)
            {
                if(er.test(v))
                {
                    vTmp = v.replace(']','');
                    vTmp = vTmp.split('[');
                    tmp = tmp[vTmp[0]];
                    console.log(tmp);
                    /*$(vTmp).each(function(k2,v2)
                    {
                        tmp = tmp[vTmp[0]][v2];
                    });*/

                    //console.log('É array: '+vTmp[0]+"\n\n");
                }else
                {
                    tmp = tmp[v];
                }

                //console.log(tmp);
            });

            console.table(tmp);

            if((typeof tmp !== 'undefined'))
            {
                var regex = new RegExp(keyArgs,"g");
                htmlTmp = htmlTmp.replace(regex,tmp);
            }



        });







       htmlReturn += htmlTmp+"\n\n\n";
    });
    return htmlReturn;
};
```

Mas não funciona. Se eu ir direto no código e digitar:

```
var tmp = valueDados.posts.post_title;
```

Eu consigo acessar o dado corretamente, porém se tentar:

```
var tmp = valueDados.valueArgs;
```

ou

```
var tmp = valueDados[valueArgs];
```

ou

```
var tmp = valueDados+"."+valueArgs;
```

nada funciona!

Alguém poderia me auxiliar como resolver isso?

Comment: Já viu o console? Já logou `valueDados` para ver o que tem dentro dele?

Comment: Então se eu dê um console só no valueDados, ele vai me retornar o objeto e consigo visualizar todos os elementos, pelo console. agora se colocar alguma das opções q citei acima dá erro. Se for a ultima ele aparece.
[object]post.post_title

Comment: Experimente logar `valueDados[0].posts.post_title;`

Comment: Você já pensou em usar uma lib de template tipo [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)?

Comment: Em javascript array e objeto tem o mesmo comportamento, você pode manipular o nome do objeto passando o chave como string, exemplo: `data[0]["posts"]["ID"]` é igual a `data[0].posts.ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Então não deu. Consegui resolver quebrando a solicitação e passando como chave, conforme código abaixo.

```
paginacaoMontaHTML = function(html,dadosJSON,argumentos)
{
    var htmlReturn = '';
    var er = new RegExp(/\[/);
    $.each(dados,function(keyDados,valueDados)
    {
        var htmlTmp = html;
        $.each(argumentos,function(keyArgs,valueArgs)
        {
            var filho = valueArgs.split('.');
            var tmp = valueDados;

            $(filho).each(function(k,v)
            {
                if(er.test(v))
                {
                    vTmp = v.replace(']','');
                    vTmp = vTmp.split('[');
                    keyVTmp = vTmp[0];
                    vTmp.shift();

                    $(vTmp).each(function(k2,v2)
                    {
                        if(typeof(tmp[keyVTmp]) == 'object')
                        {
                            if(typeof(tmp[keyVTmp][v2]) != 'undefined')
                            {
                                tmp = tmp[keyVTmp][v2];
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else
                {
                    tmp = tmp[v];
                }
            });

            if((typeof tmp !== 'undefined'))
            {
                var regex = new RegExp(keyArgs,"g");
                htmlTmp = htmlTmp.replace(regex,tmp);
            }
        });
       htmlReturn += htmlTmp+"\n\n\n";
    });
    return htmlReturn;
};
```

Muito obrigado a todos e espero que a solução seja útil para outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais simples de resolver isso é trabalhando com o próprio objeto:

```
var data = [{
    "posts": {
        "ID": 452,
        "post_date": "01\/01\/2016 15:30:00",
        "post_title": "Titulo do post"
    },
    "postmeta": {
        "anexo": {
            "size": {
                "value": "615",
                "unit": "KB"
            },
            "extension": "PDF"
        }
    },
    "taxonomies": {
        "tax_teste": {
            "term_id": 15,
            "name": "minha taxonomia",
            "slug": "minha-taxonomia"
        }
    }
}, {
    "posts": {
        "ID": 34,
        "post_date": "28\/11\/2015 10:13:22",
        "post_title": "Titulo do post2"
    },
    "postmeta": {
        "anexo": {
            "size": {
                "value": "39",
                "unit": "KB"
            },
            "extension": "JPG"
        }
    },
    "taxonomies": {
        "tax_teste": {
            "term_id": 132,
            "name": "taxonomia 2",
            "slug": "taxonomia-2"
        },
        "tax_local": {
            "term_id": 52,
            "name": "Rio de Janeiro",
            "slug": "rio-de-janeiro"
        }
    }
}];

function getData(collection, key, callResult) {
    if (collection.length > 0) {
       for(var i in collection) {
           callResult(collection[i][key]);
       }
    }
}


var posts = {}

getData(data, 'posts', function(res){
   console.log(res);
    posts = res;
});

console.log(posts)

posts.ID
posts.post_date;
posts.post_title;
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta da seguinte maneira

```
var tmp = JSON.parse(valueDados).posts
```